# Query slow when a sub select is used

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I've created a query which brings back all revenue for specific groups with different columns for YTD, Last year, the year before and the year before that.

It works but extremely slowly and from what I can tell its due to the subqueries I'm using. I've recently started a new job and previously using sub queries on MSSQL wasn't an issue and had little to no performance impact but I'm wondering if this is an issue with Postgres?

I did I limit 10 on the last query I ran and it took 3 minutes to bring back 10 lines.

code:

```
SELECT 
g.id, 
COALESCE(g.description, '') AS description,
(select sum(d.total) from ainvdet d inner join ainvhead h USING (ainvheadid) where d.product_group = g.id and  date_part('year', h.order_date) = date_part('year', current_date)) as salesytd,
(select sum(d.total) from ainvdet d inner join ainvhead h USING (ainvheadid) where d.product_group = g.id and  date_part('year', h.order_date) = date_part('year', current_date)-1) as salesytd1,
(select sum(d.total) from ainvdet d inner join ainvhead h USING (ainvheadid) where d.product_group = g.id and  date_part('year', h.order_date) = date_part('year', current_date)-2) as salesytd2,
(select sum(d.total) from ainvdet d inner join ainvhead h USING (ainvheadid) where d.product_group = g.id and  date_part('year', h.order_date) = date_part('year', current_date)-3) as salesytd3
FROM grpdesc g 
WHERE g.company = 1 AND g.record_type = 'G'
GROUP BY g.id, g.description
```

Comment: how are the indexes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without full table definitions and indexes it will be impossible to be certain, but this is most likely the case of the query being poorly written.

This should return the same result, but require the query engine to access the rows once, instead of four times (once for each subquery).

```
SELECT 
  g.id, 
  COALESCE(g.description, '') AS description,
  SUM
    (
      CASE
        WHEN date_part('year', h.order_date) = date_part('year', current_date) THEN d.total
        ELSE 0
      END
    ) AS salesytd,
  SUM
    (
      CASE
        WHEN date_part('year', h.order_date) = date_part('year', current_date) - 1 THEN d.total
        ELSE 0
      END
    ) AS salesytd1,
  SUM
    (
      CASE
        WHEN date_part('year', h.order_date) = date_part('year', current_date) - 2 THEN d.total
        ELSE 0
      END
    ) AS salesytd2,
  SUM
    (
      CASE
        WHEN date_part('year', h.order_date) = date_part('year', current_date) - 3 THEN d.total
        ELSE 0
      END
    ) AS salesytd3
FROM
  grpdesc g
LEFT JOIN
  ainvdet d
    ON d.product_group = g.id
LEFT JOIN 
  ainvhead h 
    ON h.ainvheadid = d.ainvheadid
        AND h.order_date >= date_trunc('YEAR',current_date - INTERVAL '3 YEARS')
WHERE 
  g.company = 1 
    AND g.record_type = 'G'
GROUP BY 
  g.id,
  g.description
```

I try to keep my answers as DB-agnostic as I can, but as [A Horse With No Name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) points out, in place of the `CASE` statements you can use:

```
SUM(d.total) filter (where date_part(..) = date_part(...))
```

Comment: The CASE expressions can be simplified to `count(*) filter (where date_part(..) = date_part(...)) as salesXXX`

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
SELECT 
  g.id, 
  COALESCE(g.description, '') AS description,
  ' Sales for year: ' || DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', header.order_date)::TEXT || ' ', -- for presentation only - can be deleted!
  SUM(line.total) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', header.order_date))
FROM 
  grpdesc g, 
LEFT JOIN ainvdet  line   ON line.product_group = g.id
LEFT JOIN ainvheadid header ON header.ainvheadid = line.ainvhead
WHERE g.company = 1
  AND g.record_type = 'G'
  AND h.order_date >=  DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 YEARS');
ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', header.order_date) DESC;
```

You'll have to check for performance on your own system's h/ware - I suspect that @bbaird's might be marginally faster! Like his solution, there aren't 4 `JOIN`s from the `header` to the `line`!